# Unknown filesystem with grub, but Windows Bootloader works!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have been having this strange problem for a month or so. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Win8.1 on my Lenovo z510. It worked fine for about 5 months, but almost a month ago, I started getting error at the grub menu in grub `grub rescue>filesystem is unknown`. Sometimes I also used to get a `error:trying to read/write outside hd0` or similar.

A workaround was a few restarts, or a manual set of `root` and `insmod normal`
from the rescue prompt was to be done. 
I got fed-up with this and overwrote grub with the windows bootloader. This time, it worked(although it boots directly into Windows). I never got any error while booting. Yesterday I reinstalled ubuntu hoping it will work again but it is just like before. Anyone has any ideas/solutions on how to get ubuntu working?

Comment: Is your system using UEFI BIOS? You might want to make sure SafeBoot is disabled if you're dealing with one.

Comment: It is but both the OS are installed as Legacy. And SecureBoot is disabled too

Answer (score 0):

Try Boot-Repair

Live Boot the ubuntu and install it
or use ubuntu secure remix which have  with boot-repair in it.
Connect to internet white working with Boot-repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have already tried that. It gives the same result.